# Every matrix is a limit of a sequence of invertible matrices.

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

I'm trying to prove that every matrix $n\times n$ is a limit of a sequence of invertible matrices $n\times n$.

I know this intuitively, but I couldn't prove formally. I'm trying to prove this using the fact the set of the non-invertible matrices is closed. Am I on the right way?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If the matrix is invertible, you are done (use the constant sequence).  If the matrix is non-invertible, think about an open neighborhood of the matrix.  What happens if we add a slight "random" perturbation to the matrix?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Let $A$ be your matrix, then $A-tI$ is invertible for all sufficiently small non-zero values of $t$, so just let $t$ run through any sequence of sufficiently small values approaching zero.

Comment: Why $A-tI$ is invertible for all sufficiently small non-zero values of $t$? I mean how to prove it formally?

Comment: $A-tI$ is invertible unless its determinant is zero. $\det(A-tI)=0$ is a polynomial equation of degree $n$ in $t$, so it has at most $n$ real roots, so its nonzero roots are bounded away from zero.

Comment: I'm sorry, but why the nonzero roots are positive?

Comment: Who said they were positive? I wrote that they are bounded away from zero, that's all. In any event, there is an open interval $(0,a)$ that doesn't contain any of them, and that's all you need, right?

Comment: Yes, thank you. It's my fault. I didn't understand "bounded away from zero", I'm sorry my bad English.